# Does socket.setdefaulttimeout effects os.system?

Tags: python, curl, timeout

I just cant find this in Google, and dont know how to test by myself.

I want to set timeout for my cURL calls. (Python)

I am setting the default timeout via socket.setdefaulttimeout and then using os.system to execute curl command. And I am not sure whether this solution is not working or the curl executes really fast, so this timeout is not even applicable. If the second one is right, that is wierd because I have tried to set timeout equal to 1e-12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `os.system` [executes in a different process](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system), so any change you make in the current one will **not** affect it.

You **can** set the default timeout for curl by [supplying the `--connect-timeout` argument to it](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl).